# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with code 405 POST AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to post data in my database but every time I do try to dod it I get a 405 error. Also python has an error saying that I am submitting an empty list. Please point me in the right direction to solve this problem.

```
const axios = require('axios')

let URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/Walls/saveComments'
let HEADERS = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
let data = {
  'post': post,
  'time': time
}

axios.post(URL,data, HEADERS)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })

// Axios Call to Save A Post in Backend
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP 405 error means that the server does not allow the HTTP request method that the client sent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

The HTTP method you're using in the code example you shared is POST. Therefore, it seems that your server does not accept POST requests.

In order to fix this, either change the request method to something that is supported, or change the server to allow POST requests.