# 405 - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I’m getting this error, when I’m trying to delete from my database:

DELETE https://localhost:44366/api/products/ 405

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405

I’m able to delete with Postman. My Get, and Put works

I use:

Azure DB

React

ASP.NET Core API

MSSQL

React:
DbProvider.js:

```
   deleteProduct: async (id) => {
          let response = await axios.delete(this.state.baseApi + `/products/` + id)
          return response.data;
        }
```

**UPDATE** EditorProducts.js:

```
      import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

//confirm box
import confirm from "reactstrap-confirm";

// Icons
import { FaTrash } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaEdit } from "react-icons/fa";
// Context
import DbContext from "../../../context/DbContext";

const EditorProducts = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState();
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
  const context = useContext(DbContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    context.getProducts().then((x) => setProducts(x));
  }, [refresh]);

  const handleDelete = useCallback(async (event) => {
    event.persist();

    await confirm().then((response) => {
      console.log(event.target.id);
      console.log(response);

      if (response) {
    
        context.deleteProduct(event.target.id).then(() => setRefresh(true));
      }
    });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {products != null ? 
            products.map(product => (
              <tr key={product.id}>
                  <th scope="row">{product.id}</th>
                  <td>{product.title}</td>
                  <td>{product.image}</td>
                  <td>
                    {/* EDIT PRODUCT */}
                    <Link to={`/editor/product/${product.id}`}>
                      <FaEdit style={iconStyle} />
                    </Link>
                    {/* DELETE PRODUCT */}
                    <a to="#" id={product.id} onClick={handleDelete}>
                      <FaTrash style={iconStyle} />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))
            : "Loading"}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

const iconStyle = {
  boxSizing: "unset",
  padding: "5px",
  PointerEvents: "none",
};

export default EditorProducts;
```

ProductsController.cs

```
   // DELETE: api/Products/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> DeleteProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Products.Remove(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return product;
        }

        private bool ProductExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Products.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
```

Comment: Your route just doesn't have a handler for DELETE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the route to this and remove return product since it would be deleted already

```
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteProduct(int id)
  var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Products.Remove(product);
           var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

           if (result ==0) return BadRequest();
           return Ok();
        }
```

and javascript

```
 let response = await axios.delete(this.state.baseApi + `/products/deleteproduct/` + id)
```

Comment: Hello sir! Thanks for your time.
Now i'm getting error: 400
DELETE https://localhost:44366/api/products/deleteproduct/ 400

Comment: @nemt I updated my answer. You should not use  return product since it is deleted.

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: @nemt pls  show the error you have now

Comment: This is what i get: https://imgur.com/a/edxywkZ

Comment: @nemt check your id. It  is null.

Comment: You're right, i'm not getting the id.
I've updated the EditorProducts.js code snippet

Comment: I figured it out. I deleted: <FaTrash style={iconStyle} />
Thanks for your time

Comment: I am happy that you are settled now.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277110/uncaught-in-promise-error-request-failed-with-code-405-post-axios).
Here is the accepted answer from [Raphael Rafatpanah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1911755/raphael-rafatpanah)

> The HTTP 405 error means that the server does not allow the HTTP request method that the client sent.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405
> The HTTP method you're using in the code example you shared is POST.
> Therefore, it seems that your server does not accept POST requests.

In order to fix this, either change the request method to something that is supported, or change the server to allow POST requests.